# Schedule an email delivery of a Dashboard in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have recently migrated from UA (Universal Analytics) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4).
In UA, we had the ability to schedule a Dashboard / Report delivered to the leadership on a monthly basis, and they used to get the report in their email inbox.

In GA4, we do not see share option, where I could configure a scheduled email delivery of a dashboard/ report. What is the preferred alternative in GA4 to achieve this functionality ?

The report that we used to send, has information on (1) Total Number of Users, (2) Sessions, (3) Bounce Rate, (4) Average Session Duration etc...

I have seen several articles saying GA4 will not support sharing reports via scheduled email. But could not find the same in any official google documentation.

Thanks!
Abhilash

I could find only the "Insight" option which is close to what I am looking for. But Insight is a notification based on an event. What I want is to sent a dashboard on a regular basis via email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GA4 lacks the feature to send scheduled emails, except for **Insights**. As an alternative, you may visualize the data in Looker Studio and email the reports on a [defined schedule](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9263641?hl=en#create-email&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Clooker-studio-free-version).